# Rule Engine in .net

Tags: rule-engine

I have to import data from excel to SQL database. Excel data contains various parameters like P1,P1,P4,P5 etc. I have to apply business rules Like if( P1 > 100 and P1 < 200) then insert the record in database. Similarly in some cases string values  are also validated. Can I have any open source rule engine that contains UI to change , add , delete the rules. Am using C# to read the excel and and insert the records

One more thing which is best approach:

1. Read excel first and store every record as an object in a collection, then iterate through the collection, apply business rules on every object and then insert record in the database
   Or
2. Read one record from excel apply business rule and then insert record in the database. Repeat the process for whole excel.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's not an open source solution but since no answer has been suggested I'll put it out there in case you find it helpful.  My company wrote a simple deterministic rules engine that we have used in several similar projects. Our [Enigma RulesEngine](http://www.enigmasupercomputing.com/RulesEngine) is based on Windows Workflow so it's great for a .NET environment and the user interface for creating new rules has all the simplicity that comes with the drag-and-drop WF framework.

To attempt an answer for your second question, I think it depends on the size of your import data. If your excel files are less than 100 Megabytes or so I would just convert the whole thing into a collection of objects first. I think you might gain some speed from doing it more as a batch process than in singles.

Of course if they are large files or you have low memory problems you could always compromise the two suggestions you made: read in 1000 records into a collection at a time, repeat until the import is done.